# Storing parent child mapping in memory. To list all reachable child for a parent efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have parent and child mappings in reational database as below,

```
relationship_id | parent_id | child_id
1               | 100009    | 600009
2               | 100009    | 600010
3               | 600010    | 100008
```

for performance optimization, i like to keep all these mappings in memory.
Here, a child will be having more than one parent and a parent has more than 2 children.
I guess, i should use "Graph" data structure.

Populating into memory is a one time activity. My concern is that, when I ask to list all child (not only immediate child) it should return them as fast as possible. Addition and deletion happens rarely.
What data structure and algorithm I should use?

Tried [MultiHashMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiHashMap.html), to achieve `O(1)` search time, but it has more redundancy.

Answer (score 5):

Have a graph data structure for parent-child relationships. Each GraphNode can just have an `ArrayList` of children.

Then have `HashMap` that maps ID to GraphNode.

You need to figure something out so you don't create a cycle (if this is possible) which will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: This what exactly I did. But, I need to get all reachable children for a parent. In this design, I need to travel through every children-children node to find the reach ability. Is there any way I can find all reachable nodes in less traversal.

Comment: @krishna I'm not sure whether it can be much better than that. You could have a flag on each node to indicate that you've visited it so you don't repeat any nodes. This flag can be efficiently implemented for multiple calls (to get descendants) as an integer, starting at 0 and incrementing on each call, and then only visiting nodes if its value != that value and then set each visited node to this value.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom `Node` class and a hashmap to store node references for easy lookup.

```
for each row in database
if parent node exists in map
  get it
else
  create it and add it

if child node exists in map
  get it
else
  create it and add it

set relationship between parent and child
```

The node class would look something like;

```
public class Node {

  private int id;

  private List<Node> parents = new ArrayList<Node>();
  private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

  //getters and setters

}
```

Comment: This what exactly I did. But, I need to get all reachable children for a parent. In this design, I need to travel through every children-children node to find the reach ability. Is there any way I can find all reachable nodes in less traversal.

Comment: Do you think the traversal is going to be a problem? Its a pretty standard approach; just think how trees work. The alternative would be to have a list of all descendants on each node.